# Three20 TTWebController ignores supported url schemes registered by app in TTURLMap

Tags: iphone, three20

We are using TTWebController to display web pages served by our server.  I would like these pages to include urls to be handled by the iphone app.  Eg:

page.html:

```
<a href="myapp://profile">Show Profile On Phone"</a>
```

AppDelegate.m

```
TTUrlMap* map= navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toViewcontroller:[TTWebController class]];
[map from:@"myapp://profile" toViewcontroller:[ProfileController class]];
```

When the page displays on the phone in the TTWebController, clicking the link doesn't display the ProfileController, nothing happens.  I would expect TTWebController to recognize that the scheme is registered, run the normal TTNavigator magic and show the associated controller.  Is there a way to do this?

Note: registering the URL scheme with the app itself doesn't work either, ie. TTWebController doesn't recognize the url and call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `TTWebController` registers itself as the `UIWebViewDelegate` of the `UIWebView`, so you can override `-[UIWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]` -- e.g. if your URLs all start with `myapp:`, then you could do this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
  shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked &&
      [request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"myapp"])
  {
    // This is our private URL
    TTOpenURL([request.URL absoluteString]);
    return NO;
  }
  else
  {
    return [super webView:webView 
                  shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
                  navigationType:navigationType];
  }
}
```